# Como fazer para o Widget filho de uma Column expanda para a largura maxima do pai(Column)?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
Form(
    child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    CustomTextFormField("E-mail"),
    CustomTextFormField('Senha'),
       Expanded(
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              child: Text(
                'Entrar',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ))
```

Esse é meu código, quando uso o **Expanded** o **Widget** simplesmente some.
Estou seguindo o exato exemplo que achei na [documentação do Flutter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

O que estou fazendo de errado??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizar o `Expanded` no filho da `Column` deverá ser o suficiente, contudo, pode sempre tentar adicionar como propriedade da coluna: `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` para fazer com que todos os filhos desta ocupem a largura total.

O `SizedBox` aqui com `BoxFit.fitWidth` não é necessário para alcançar este fim, na verdade, é ambíguo não trazendo nada de novo.